# How do I stop my iPhone camera automatically recording my location when I take photos?

Tags: iphone, camera, geolocation

I already know I can go into my iPhone’s Privacy settings and select what apps can use my camera. My question is not about stopping apps from using my camera. It is about not allowing photos and videos taken by any app to also capture my location when taking them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you’re already on the right track, as you also do this within your iPhone’s Privacy settings. More specifically:

1. Go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services
2. To the right of each app that is listed you’ll see an indication of when it accesses your location
3. Now tap on any of the apps you’d like to change the location settings of (Hint: you can also select the default Camera app to change its settings)
4. Exit Settings

Any photos/videos you now take with an app that you've chosen to 'Never' allow access to your location, will not be able to record your location.